# Чтение 1 csv файла 20 минут

Tags: python, память

подскажите пожалуйста что происходит.
Пытаюсь прочитать csv он весит 5Гб. Работаю через jupyter. Всегда грузил очень быстро. Пару дней назад стал сильно тормозить, обычно мне нужно прочитать несколько таких файлов, всегда работало без нареканий. Сейчас компьютер начинает зависать когда читаю большие файлы. Несколько раз приходилось перезагружать комп.
Пробовал сделать gc.collect() не помогло. Все равно очень медленно грузит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А диск HDD или SSD?

Comment: Диск hhd.  Одна ячейка .

Comment: Сам HDD не начал сыпаться ли?

Comment: Я бы проверил не выпал ли диск в PIO mode вместо DMA. Настройки Bios не сбрасывались случайно? Ну или если ошибки диска были мог в него выпасть.

Comment: причин на самом деле может быть великое множество. Может раньше файлы читались из `disk cache`, а сейчас подгружаются с диска; может диск начал сыпаться как коллеги предположили; может у Jupyter закончилась память и началась подгрузка файла подкачки; etc.

Comment: А если в jupyter закончилась память. Как почистить?

Comment: Видимо перезапустить его )

Comment: Kernel -> Restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыл для себя библиотеку Dask. Быстро читает файлы, после обработки данных можно вернуть в pd.dataframe

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('/Users/log/*-*-*.csv', sample=25000000)
```

Этот код читает сразу всю папку у меня, и не нужно делать разные циклы.
Также неплохо объединять с pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html
Что бы быстрее выводить информацию

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример использования библиотеки из вашего кода :)

Comment: Ну она на самом деле сразу то ничего не делает, реальное чтение и вообще операции происходят в момент вызова `.compute()` насколько я помню. И не всегда `Dask` это панацея от всего )